# PostgreSQL : what are simple quotation marks for?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, quotation-marks

How could I remove simple quotation marks that appear in empty cells? See image below

[image: View of a table including simple quotation marks]

The columns can be either TEXT or CHARACTER VARYING(), these signs are still present. I have other tables with no quotation marks in empty cells... The extract above is the result of an importation of an ORACLE table into my PGSQL database. This is probably the reason why.

Comment: This might be related to the software displaying the values. What is it ? It might also be related to the import. How was it done ? Right now, the question lacks the necessary information to be answered.

Comment: The software is pgAdmin III. The table was imported with Navicat tool that allows connection to various database types and migration of data between databases.

Comment: `''` indicates empty string, which is different than Null in PostgreSQL. Here, I'd venture that those empty strings are supposed to be nulls, but Navicat inserted empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess it that the importation process introduced single quotes. If this query solves it

```
select num_position, replace(num_position, '''', '')
from t;
```

then replace all single quotes

```
update t
set
    num_position = replace(num_position, '''', ''),
    num_plan = replace(num_plan, '''', '')
```